# Count key value that matches certain value in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe that has a column which value is string json. How can I count the value that match certain value in a list inside the dictionary and report back as a column?

For example, below is the dataframe:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|col                                                                        |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"field":{"list":[{"item":1,"upgrade":false},{"item":2,"upgrade":true}]}}
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|{"field":{"list":[{"item":1,"upgrade":false},{"item":2,"upgrade":false}]}}
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I would like to count how many "upgrade" key in the list is false.

So the ideal dataframe will look like this:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|col                                                                        | upgrade_false
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
|{"field":{"list":[{"item":1,"upgrade":false},{"item":2,"upgrade":true}]}}   | 1
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|{"field":{"list":[{"item":1,"upgrade":false},{"item":2,"upgrade":false}]}}  | 2
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is the column a string? Spark doesn't have dictionary types.

Comment: @mck yes it's string. sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is probably to count the number of times `"upgrade":false` has appeared. Then we don't need to parse the json at all:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn('upgrade_false', F.size(F.split('col', '"upgrade":false')) - 1)
df2.show()
+--------------------+-------------+
|                 col|upgrade_false|
+--------------------+-------------+
|{"field":{"list":...|            1|
|{"field":{"list":...|            2|
+--------------------+-------------+
```